# True or false for some questions on measure on $(X,\mathcal{A})$

Tags: measure-theory

Let $(X,\mathcal{A},\mu)$ be a measure space.  Let $\{A_i\}_{i\geq 1}$ be a decreasing sequence in $\mathcal{A}$. The following questions should be answered yes or no, and giving a reason such as a proof or a counterexample.

1) If $\mu(A_n)\leq 1/n$ for all $n\geq 1$, then $\mu\left ( \bigcap _{n\geq 1}A_n \right )$. I answered yes due to continuity of measures from above, 
$$\mu\left ( \bigcap _{n\geq 1}A_n \right )=\lim_{n\to\infty}\mu (A_n)\leq \lim_{n\to\infty}\mu (A_n)\leq \lim_{n\to\infty}1/n=0,$$
and since $\mu$ is positive, we have $\mu\left ( \bigcap _{n\geq 1}A_n \right )=0$.

2) If $\mu(A_n)\geq 1$ for all $n\geq 1$, then $\mu\left ( \bigcap _{n\geq 1}A_n \right )\geq 1$. I answered yes. First, $\mu(A_n)\geq 1$ for all $n$, so taking the limit on both sides, we have $\lim_{n\to\infty} \mu(A_n)\geq 1$. Thus $$\mu\left ( \bigcap _{n\geq 1}A_n \right )=\lim_{n\to\infty}\mu (A_n)\geq 1.$$

3) If $1\leq \mu(A_n)\leq 2$ for all $n\geq 1$, then $\mu\left ( \bigcap _{n\geq 1}A_n \right )\geq 1$. I answeres yes, as it doesn't matter about the upper bound of $\mu(A_n)$.

Comment: For 3), what about $A_n = (n,\infty)$ and $\mu$ the Lebesgue measure on $\Bbb{R}$?

Comment: @PhoemueX If $A_n=(n,\infty)$, then $\mu(A_n)=\infty-n=\infty$, when $\mu$ is lebesgue measure on $\mathbb{R}$. Are my other reasons correct in the post?

Comment: I think there is nothing wrong. Your explanations are correct.

Comment: @UnknownW: Sorry, my example was meant for 2), not for 3). What is $\bigcap_n A_n$ in this example? What is its measure?

Comment: @PhoemueX It is empty, so the measure of it is zero. I figured the rest out, thanks :).

Comment: @UnknownW: For other people looking at this question, it might be helpful if you post your insight as an answer, or to edit it into your question. As a side effect, this might also generate you some reputation :)